# Running Blocks of Code Concurrently in Swift 3 Function Followed by Wait for Completion

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I am having trouble understanding how dispatch queues or task handlers work in swift 3.  My specific problem is:  I am having performance issues and want to run multiple blocks of code in parallel and wait to exit the function until all of the blocks complete.  I tried to simply run the the blocks asynchronously in the background, but then I get "attempting to use xxx while it is mutating" because I enumerate over the same arrays or enumerateChildNodes(...) being managed on the asynchronous queues.  I am trying to manage minimizing SpriteKit nodes to improve fps.  Here is an example of the code blocks that I want to run in parallel and them wait:

```
  func determinePlatformNodesToUse() {

    // Code Block 1:
    for platform in platformArray {
        addPlatformNode(platform, leftDistance: leftDistance, rightDistance: rightDistance)
    }

    // Also part of Code Block 1:
    // resort the platform nodes to guarantee position sequence
    currentPlatformNodeArray.sort(by: { $0.position.x < $1.position.x })

    // Code Block 2:
    for character in characterArray {
        if character.type == CharacterType.Enemy {
            addCharacterNode(character, leftDistance: leftDistance, rightDistance: rightDistance)
        }
    }

    // Code block 3
    // put all the enemies into an array for update processing will be added in addCharacterNode
    currentMotionEnemyNodeArray.removeAll()

    // Also part of Code block 3
    foregroundNode.enumerateChildNodes(withName: CharacterType.Enemy.rawValue, using: {
        (node, stop) in
        if let enemy = node as? CharacterNode {
            if enemy.motionType != .Stand { // dont use .Stand as they dont have motion
                self.currentMotionEnemyNodeArray.append(enemy)
            }
        }
    })

    // Code Block 4
    for actionSceneObject in actionSceneObjectArray {
        addActionSceneObjectNode(actionSceneObject, leftDistance: leftDistance, rightDistance: rightDistance)
    }

    // At this point, wait until all blocks 1-4 above have finished

    // Run blocks 5 - 8 code in all in parallel

    // wait until blocks 5 - 8 have finished and then leave the function
  }
```

Comment: Hi, please let me know if your problem is resolved

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you are trying to do using `NSOperation`. It can be done in the following way:

```
func determinePlatformNodesToUse(completion: (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {

    let queue:OperationQueue = OperationQueue()
    queue.name = "com.SOQA.SOQA.name"
    queue.qualityOfService = QualityOfService.default
    queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 6

    let operation01:BlockOperation = BlockOperation { 
        // Code Block - 1
    }

    let operation02:BlockOperation = BlockOperation {
        // Code Block - 2
    }

    let operation03:BlockOperation = BlockOperation {
        // Code Block - 3
    }

    let operation04:BlockOperation = BlockOperation {
        // Code Block - 4
    }

    let operation05:BlockOperation = BlockOperation {
        // Code Block - 5
    }

    let operation06:BlockOperation = BlockOperation {
        // Code Block - 6
    }

    let operation07:BlockOperation = BlockOperation {
        // Code Block - 7
    }

    let operation08:BlockOperation = BlockOperation {
        // Code Block - 8
    }

    operation05.addDependency(operation01)
    operation05.addDependency(operation02)
    operation05.addDependency(operation03)
    operation05.addDependency(operation04)

    operation06.addDependency(operation01)
    operation06.addDependency(operation02)
    operation06.addDependency(operation03)
    operation06.addDependency(operation04)

    operation07.addDependency(operation01)
    operation07.addDependency(operation02)
    operation07.addDependency(operation03)
    operation07.addDependency(operation04)

    operation08.addDependency(operation01)
    operation08.addDependency(operation02)
    operation08.addDependency(operation03)
    operation08.addDependency(operation04)

    queue.addOperations([operation01, operation02, operation03, operation04, operation05, operation06, operation07, operation08], waitUntilFinished: true)
}
```

Feel free to comment if you have any doubts in using this example. Feel free to suggest edits to make this better :)

Comment: This approach works great the first time through, but the second time through, I get a mutation exception.  Is this queue running on the main thread?  Otherwise I think the update function is being called again while the queue is still running.  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x17405bcc0> was mutated while being enumerated.'
*** First throw call stack: